# Install Line 6 Toneport UX1

Tags: installation, command-line

**What am I trying to do?**

As the title suggests, I am trying to install the the Line 6 Toneport UX1 software.

**What is the problem?**

Upon reaching the step where I am told to enter `sudo apt-get install linux-headers` into Terminal in [this article](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-a-line6-guitarport-or-toneport-ux1-or-gx.html#more-1881), I am confronted with the following message...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers is a virtual package provided by:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-27-lowlatency 3.5.0-27.30
  linux-headers-3.5.0-26-lowlatency 3.5.0-26.28
  linux-headers-3.5.0-25-lowlatency 3.5.0-25.25
  linux-headers-3.5.0-24-lowlatency 3.5.0-24.23
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23-lowlatency 3.5.0-23.22
  linux-headers-3.5.0-22-lowlatency 3.5.0-22.21
  linux-headers-3.5.0-21-lowlatency 3.5.0-21.19
  linux-headers-3.5.0-18-lowlatency 3.5.0-18.18
  linux-headers-3.5.0-27-generic 3.5.0-27.46
  linux-headers-3.5.0-27 3.5.0-27.46
  linux-headers-3.5.0-26-generic 3.5.0-26.42
  linux-headers-3.5.0-26 3.5.0-26.42
  linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic 3.5.0-25.39
  linux-headers-3.5.0-25 3.5.0-25.39
  linux-headers-3.5.0-24-generic 3.5.0-24.37
  linux-headers-3.5.0-24 3.5.0-24.37
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic 3.5.0-23.35
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23 3.5.0-23.35
  linux-headers-3.5.0-22-generic 3.5.0-22.34
  linux-headers-3.5.0-22 3.5.0-22.34
  linux-headers-3.5.0-21-generic 3.5.0-21.32
  linux-headers-3.5.0-21 3.5.0-21.32
  linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic 3.5.0-19.30
  linux-headers-3.5.0-19 3.5.0-19.30
  linux-headers-3.5.0-18-generic 3.5.0-18.29
  linux-headers-3.5.0-18 3.5.0-18.29
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17-lowlatency 3.5.0-17.18
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic 3.5.0-17.28
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17 3.5.0-17.28
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'linux-headers' has no installation candidate
```

**What have I done?**

I've gone through the list of linux-headers (e.g. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-27-lowlatency 3.5.0-27.30` and onward) and I receive a message that reads as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package x.x.x-x.x
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'x.x.x-x.x'
```

Granted this article may be pretty old, I think perhaps the final line `E: Package 'linux-headers' has no installation candidate` means they could've been taken down.

**My specifications**

- Ubuntu 12.10
- OS type: 64 bit

Comment: Any reason you split this into two questions, which isn't acceptable here?  (I've edited your part 2 into this question here)

Comment: @TheLordofTime It is a separate question.  The software did install properly, but it's actually a problem with the VirtualBox and USB port settings.  This question was about installation in the Terminal.

Comment: then you should not split them in parts, but rather say "This is a different question".  The titles suggested "merging".  I rolled back my edits, but you need to state the difference in the questions

Comment: @TheLordofTime Okay, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, I can't believe I missed this...

```
uname -r
```

That command will display the version to install.  Everything is very straightforward after that.